# Problem unlock disk encrypt

Tags: ubuntu

I've got a problem while unlucking my laptop hd encrypt. The Caps Lock isn't working while I try to unlock. Its strange because the capslock does work before they ask to unlock the disk encrypt. How do I fix this bug?

I use Ubuntu with Linux 5.0.0-16.

Comment: Do you use LUKS? I found this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1344194. It's for Fedora of course but it seems to be something in LUKS?

Comment: Well, I dont know what is Luks, Ive chosen to encrypt my hd when i installed Linux ubuntu. But the difference is that my capslock key or shift doesnt work. In the bug that you send was only the light that wasnt working.... And besides the capslock key my numlock isnt working either.

Comment: I also tryied with another keyboard connecting with usb but it didn't work